# C++ curious behavior in vector::push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I have the following data-structure as a class named "Task":

```
private:
string name;
int computation_time;
int period;
```

Furthermore i have a ASCII-File with this content:

```
A 3 10
B 2 12
C 1 11
```

name = A, computation_time = 3, period = 10 and so on....

Now i want to read in the file, create Task-object and push it back into a vector:

```
void read_in_task_list_and_create_tasks(const string &filename, vector<Task> &current_tasks)
{
    ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open(filename.c_str());

    string tmp_name;
    int tmp_computation_time;
    int tmp_period;

    while(!in_file.eof())
    {
        in_file >> tmp_name;
        in_file >> tmp_computation_time;
        in_file >> tmp_period;

//        Task tmp_task(tmp_name, tmp_computation_time, tmp_period);
//        current_tasks.push_back(tmp_task);
        current_tasks.push_back(Task(tmp_name, tmp_computation_time, tmp_period));
    }
}
```

Now, when i take a look into current_tasks vector, it has elements, but their values dont match my in_file values.
Watch the outcommented lines. tmp_task object is exactly correct, but if it's getting pushed back, it loses it's values like descriped above.

Could this be a Copy-Constructor Issue in Task-class, because std::vector is managing the memory-allocation?

I'm using netbeans with g++ compiler on Linux x86.

THX

Comment: Can you post the complete definition for the `Task` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure there are no copy constructors or assignment operators defined.

The automatic ones should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

At least IMO, you're taking somewhat the wrong approach, trying to do too much work yourself. The standard library can already handle most of what you're doing. All you really need to do is specify how to read a single object from the stream:

```
struct Task { 
    std::string name;
    int computation_time;
    int period;
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Task &t) {
    return is >> t.name >> t.computation_time >> t.period;
}
```

Then you can use a standard algorithm to actually read the data and put it into your vector:

```
void read_in_task_list_and_create_tasks(const string &filename, 
                                        vector<Task> &current_tasks) 
{
    std::ifstream in(filename.c_str());

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Task>(in), 
              std::istream_iterator<Task>(),
              std::back_inserter(current_tasks));
}
```

As a bonus, this will also fix the problem you had with seeming to read the last item in the file twice because your loop was wrong (yes, I know you didn't mention that, but based on how you wrote your loop, it's essentially unavoidable).

Comment: well i dont have that problem because my file does not end with newline, but ty anyways this is a very fast and easy approach to get such things done!

Comment: +1, Nice use of the STL algorithms. I fixed some typos in the spelling of `istream_iterator` for you.

Answer (score 2):

Does Task have the copy constructor and assignment operator defined?  When you push the object into the vector it's not pushing that exact one in, it's copying it.  So I believe you'll need one of those to be defined (I don't remember which, but it's always good to define both if you define either).

Comment: The default copy-constructor should be doing the right thing with the given members.  Of course, if Askener declared his own copy-constructor, he needs to make sure that it works.

Comment: I forget, is it copy constructor or operator= that needs to be overriden here?

Comment: Task::Task(const Task& orig)
{

}                                                                      this is what netbeans created for me. is this a pre-defined copy-constructor? because when i say this->name = orig.get_name() i get an error....

Comment: @Askener, that copy constructor is the right signature, but it also means it replaces the normal compiler-generated default, which would have done a simple copy of the members. Netbeans' provided copy constructor stub does not do any copying of the member data so that will explain the behavior you are seeing. In this situation, since you are not allocating your own memory, you could delete Netbeans' generated copy constructor (and assignment operator if it made one)

Comment: @Herms - if you define 1 of them, you should define both. The Law of the Big Three: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: @orip Agreed that both should be defined.  I just couldn't remember which was actually used here.

Comment: @ orip - i only define copy contructors if i allocate memory in my class with new or assign pointers. i dont do this normally when attributes get allocated on the stack

Comment: @Herms - I forgot to say +1, since you nailed it when you asked about the copy ctor

Comment: FWIW, I C++0x should allow emplace_back(), which does not use the copy constructor. But since the copy constructor would be used to shift elements when resizing (or does it use `move` now?) you'd still need to make sure it's properly implemented.

Comment: @beldaz: yes, elements are moved instead of copied, so (for one example), `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>` should work fine (even though you can't copy a `unique_ptr`).

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks. So much to like about C++0x. Just wish it would become the current standard ASAP rather than the limbo we're living in now.

Comment: @beldaz: I don't think finalizing it will make a huge difference at this point -- the compiler teams are already adding the new features about as fast as they can anyway...